# How to get managedObjectContext from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In AppDelegete.m there is method:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)shared
{
 return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
}
```

How can I get managedObjectContext in other classes (i.e. without creation appropriate properties) using that method?

Comment: how is managedObjectCOntext declared in Appdelegate ?

Comment: as a @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;